# Basic logic for the interior of a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm currently painstakingly working my way through the basics of Topology and I'm on interior sets. My textbook provides this basic question for me to prove

> Question to solve
>
> Show that interior satisfies $\operatorname{int}A=(\bar{A'})'$

So, the interior of a set $A$ is the largest open set contained inside $A$, and this question wants me to relate that definition to the idea that the closed complement of A forms an interior set when again made to a complement.

My first idea to proving this is to simplify the question by moving the second complement over the equal so the LHS is now of the form $(\operatorname{int}A)'$. After that...I'm not sure how to progress. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused by your idea. Recall that to show equality, you want to show both inclusions. So take an element of the interior and show it lies in the complement of the closure of the complement, then do the same in the other direction.

Comment: What exactly does the element of the interior look like algebraically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that the interior of $A$ is also the union of all open sets contained in $A$. So, to check that $x\in \textrm{int}(A)$, it suffices to obtain an open $U$ such that $x\in U\subseteq A$.

If an element $x$ is in the interior, then there is an open set $U$ such that $x\in U\subseteq A$, hence $x$ is not in the closure of the complement of $A$, therefore $\textrm{int}(A)\subseteq (\bar{A^c})^c$. Conversely, if $x\in(\bar{A^c})^c$, then there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ disjoint from $A^c$ for $x$ is not in the closure of $A^c$, therefore $U\subset A$, hence $x\in \textrm{int}(A)$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it is very good. But I'm having trouble understanding your justification for $\textrm{int}(A)\subseteq (\bar{A^c})^c$. You stated that x is not in closure of the complement of A (which makes sense), but we are dealing with the complement of the closure of the complement of A. It feels like there needs to be a bit more justification for that extra "complement" being applied and what it means for the set in relation to A.

Comment: @Dylan if $x$ is not in the closure of the complement, then it is in the complement of the closure of the complement, i.e., $x\notin \bar{A^c}\iff x\in (\bar{A^c})^c$.